# Angular Instagram/Youtube back button restore data and scroll position

Tags: javascript, angular, youtube, instagram

How to replicate the Youtube/Instagram functionality, when user clicks the browser back button, he is redirected to the previous page with the same data and scroll position (without reloading the data)?

What tool/packages can be used and what the whole process would look like.
I tried to search for possible solutions but couldn't find any helpful results.

Comment: please share code to understand problem clearly

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [@angular/router](https://angular.io/api/router) for navigation, the [RouteReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy) interface is what you're looking for.
Specifically, the [shouldreuseroute](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy#shouldreuseroute) method will let you configure if you want to reuse some route; this will prevent the route's mapped component (the component loaded when this route is activated) from being destroyed after user navigates away from this route (or from this page). If a route is configured to be reused, the corresponding page component will be cached and will be displayed as-is, the next time this route is hit.

If you do not want to use this approach or if you do not use [@angular/router](https://angular.io/api/router), another (dirty, less preferred) approach would be to cache your data and scroll position to an Angular Service which is declared in the AppModule (so that it does not get destroyed when you switch components or modules) and is injected in the component whose data you want to preserve.

But I'd go for the first approach.

A tutorial for RouteReuseStrategy:

https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/angular-route-reuse-strategy-b5d40adce841